# Resultant of fourier coefficients is very sensitive to window size?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

I'm trying to make a frequency analyzer using a windowed fourier series in flash, but the size of my window greatly affects magnitude of the coefficients.

I'm using a formula from a textbook to calculate the coefficients at every frame:

```
     N-1
Ak = SUM { cos(freq*n*deltax) * pcmFloatValue}
     n=0

     N-1
Bk = SUM { sin(freq*n*deltax) * pcmFloatValue}
     n=0
```

Where *deltax* is the time interval in between samples, and *pcmFloatValue* is the time domain value at *n*deltax*. In the textbook, the integral limits are 0 to 2PI, and the integral is then divided by PI...but I thought I could use it for any interval and eliminate the division.

so my code to get the magnitude of the frequency is here:

```
        var deltax:Number = 1 / 44100;
        var sumCos:Number = 0;
        var sumSin:Number = 0;
        var c:Number = 0;

        while (frameba.bytesAvailable > 32) {
            //trace("getMag", frameba.bytesAvailable);
            c++;
            var freq:Number = (number / (2 * Math.PI));
            var sample:Number = frameba.readFloat();

            sumCos += sample * deltax;
            sumCos *= Math.cos(freq * c * deltax)

            sumSin += sample * deltax;
            sumSin *=Math.sin(freq * c * deltax)
        }


        return Math.sqrt(sumCos * sumCos + sumSin * sumSin);
```

*number* is frequency in Hz, and *frameba* is a mono sampling of the audio at 44100 hz. I call this function every frameba I grab, which corresponds to this code:

```
        var endCounter:Number = int(s.length / number); //get number of frames
        frameData = new Array();

        for ( var i:Number = 0; i < endCounter-1; i++) {
            var frameba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

            var frameSize:Number = int((number / 1000) * 44100) * 4;
            monoba.readBytes(frameba, 0, frameSize);// grab new frame

            frameba.position = 0;
            var mag:Number=getMag(512, frameba); //this function is the code snippet i posted before this one
            frameData.push(mag*100000);
```

So the problem is that the magnitude of the two coefficients gets extremely large when I change the window sometimes, and it's not linear. When the window is 42 milliseconds I get values like this:

```
    ...,0.46867691675958506,0.40119205703768124,1.076056196209733,0.4138200126843882,1.288280385823108,1.1605685308155427,...
```

When I set it to 100ms:

...,3.487381020768127,7.610466058045129,45.780152579896324,77.46963149803167,35.531672823487014,0.6057853252694128,...

When I set it to 500ms:

```
   ...,0.7132093539701988,0.561741462535126,0.5303097469754452,0.6267107444675019,0.5205164960161707,0.4828724689303949,...
```

So it doesn't keep increasing in average size. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not, am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the Fourier series instead of a nice FFT library like [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/)? It would take a lot of work off your hands..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fourier coefficients are sensitive to any rectangular window size (FFT/DFT length N) that is not an *exact* multiple of the period of any repetitive waveform being analyzed.

Think about it.  If you chop off just part of a full sine wave, and the part you happen to chop off leaves a mostly positive or mostly negative lobe, then that will probably bias your result by some weighted positive or negative amount.  As you move your window or change it length, different portions of one period your signal will be left over by this chopping, causing different results.

Some call it spectral leakage, others call it convolution with the window function (explicit or implied).  You can compensate for this, but it's usually easier to just use a long enough fixed length FFT with a non-rectangular window function (Hamming or Von Hann, et.al.).

Comment: This is very interesting, being that I tried to generate a single tone frequency signal, and at some frames it gave me the right constant coefficient, and at others it gave me periodic variations in coefficients, which makes sense when we are not sampling at correct multiples, hopefully i'm seeing this correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to normalize your results you need to divide the values by N. You should then get more or less consistent values which are independent of N.

Comment: I don't see how that would make a difference since N is the same for all values.

Comment: @Prasad: It may be that I didn't understand your code, but it looks like you have a fixed sample rate (44.1 kHz) and you change the window duration, hence the number of samples in your DFT, N, will also vary in proportion to your window size ?

Comment: Yes, the DFTs will vary according to window size, so they are by nature normalized.

Comment: OK - add a window function first - that should remove some of your problems - I think you'll then see that you still need a 1/N term if you want to compare DFTs of different sizes.